# Function not defined in javascript object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, callback

I'm trying to invoke a method using callbacks and object orientated javascript dealing with google api, but I keep getting an undefined error with the function being called.

js:

```
var generateMap = (function(){
var map;
return{
    offsetCenter: function(lat, lng){
        lat = lat;
        lng = lng + .01;

        return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    ,initialize: function(location){
        console.log("test");
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            draggable: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var newCenter = offsetCenter(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(newCenter);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
            title: 'Point A',
            map: map,
            draggable: false
        });
    }

    ,createMap: function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    }
};
})();
$(document).ready(function(){
    var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
    callbacks.add(
        generateMap.createMap
    );
    callbacks.fire();
})
```

Error: ReferenceError: initialize is not defined

Any reason why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `createMap` refers to a symbol that isn't defined:

```
,createMap: function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    // Here ---------------------------------^
}
```

Unlike Java or C#, JavaScript has no implied `this` for methods on the current instance. You have to specify it.

Now, because `generateMap` is a singleton, and `initialize` doesn't use `this` anywhere, you can correct it like this:

```
,createMap: function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(generateMap.initialize);
}
```

Again, that only works because `generateMap` is a singleton, and `initialize` doesn't use `this`.

---

In the general case (if it weren't a singleton, or `initialize` used `this`), you'd manage `this`:

This code:

```
callbacks.add(
    generateMap.createMap
);
```

...will add a reference to the `createMap` function to the callbacks list, but that function isn't in any way bound to the `generateMap` object. So when it's called, `this` won't refer to `generateMap` (other than closing over it, but again, we're assuming here we aren't dealing with a singleton). You can fix that with ES5's `Function#bind` or jQuery's `$.proxy`:

```
callbacks.add(
    generateMap.createMap.bind(generateMap)
);
// or
callbacks.add(
    $.proxy(generateMap.createMap, generateMap)
);
```

Each of those creates a function that, when called, will turn around and call `createMap` making `this = generateMap` during the call.

Then in `createMap`, we fix the `initialize` thing in a similar way:

```
,createMap: function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.initialize.bind(this));
}
// or
,createMap: function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($.proxy(this.initialize, this));
}
```

More about `this` in JavaScript on my blog:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)